# Tumblr. Cross-Origin Sharing Policy and ColorThief.js in a custom theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, cross-domain, tumblr

I build a tumblr theme that heavily relies on [colorthief.js](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/) and after loading `colorthief.js` and a `.js` file *(with simple colorthief code implementation - get dominant color from image and apply to a button)* I got console error: `Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

Is there any way to bypass this policy by some inline js? I wrote the part of getting the colors from image and applying them to the button with jQuery. I'm just looking for a way to bypass cross-origin data policy or a smart way to do it differently.

Comment: What are the two domains in question?

Comment: blog is on someblog.tumblr.com and images are on xx.media.tumblr.com/

Comment: I ask as it should be possible to load all of the colorthief.js directly into your template. Or even link to it after using the tumblr upload option. https://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file, but I am still unsure if the call is being made cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to bypass this policy by some inline js?

No. The site supplying the data must give foreign JavaScript permission to access it.

Comment: I've read that there is a way to do it with Tumblr API? Can it really be done and used on multiple sites?